# Get name property from an svg onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

How do to get the name property from this svg onClick event in react?

I have console.logged(e.target) after the onClick event and here is what I get:

```
e.target: <svg class=​"MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable=​"false" viewBox=​"0 0 24 24" aria-hidden=​"true" name=​"acceptTermsOfService">​<path d=​"M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z">​</path>​</svg>​
```

I want to get that **name** property but `e.target.name` and `e.target.svg.name` both return "undefined".

Comment: Try using the id prop instead, if you can.

Comment: Yep, i added an id prop and accessed that. Spot on. Post that as the answer and I'll accept if you like.

Comment: Supposing that the path won't take pointer events (css: `path{pointer-events:none;}`) try `console.log(e.target.attributes.name)`

Comment: @enxaneta that is awesome, I don't even need to add an id prop. Using your tip, I got the value with `e.target.attributes.name.value`. I'll experiment with `pointer-events: none` in the near future.

Comment: or ``e.target.getAttribute("name") because name is an attribute, not a property